# Completing second argument from known list

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am writing bash script. It receives two arguments. The first is just a string that the user can specify however she wants. The second argument however has to be a member of a known set, e.g. `apple`, `banana`, `pinenut` or `pineapple`. I know how to check if the parameter is legal but I find it annoying to have to type in  the full word. I could shorten the parameters to `a`, `b`, `pn` or `pa` but that is hard to remember and a little ugly. Is there a way to provide auto complete so that the user can press "a+tab" and it will automatically complete to `apple`?

Comment: you can read about it in this thread with examples:

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete

Comment: You can write a bash completion function for your script if you want to do that, sure. The man page has some documentation about doing that as does the general internet I'm sure.

Comment: Those answers say how to add autocomplete, but the same autocomplete will work for all parameter. It doesn't address how to add only for the second. I will keep looking.

Comment: Found answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33236/configure-autocomplete-for-the-first-argument-leave-the-others-alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function autocomp_fruit_script {
  local cur opts
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  fruit="apple banana pinenut pineapple"
  if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 2 ]; then
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${fruit}" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
  fi
}
complete -o nospace -F autocomp_fruit_script fruit_script
```

Where `fruit_script` is my script.